# how to display numbers without garbage numbers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

Hi friends,

whenever I press the numbers in textfield it's take upto 9 numbers my textfield has taken

right values but when I press 10 th number, I have found duplicate number.

in my header file I declare a pressnumber is "long long int"

```
-(IBAction)press:(id)sender{

pressNumber = pressNumber*10 + (int)[sender tag];

phonenumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",pressNumber];

}
```

I want to enter a phone number in my textfiled but it is not taken 10 right numbers.
Thanking you,

Comment: try using "%lld" instead of "%d" in the string format

Comment: @mshsayem hi friend, it is working in only text filed but it has not taken in      long long int x - [phonenumber.text intValue];NSLOg(@"%lld",x); i enter the number in textfiled is 9956565656 but the output is 2147483647

Comment: Phone numbers should be stored as strings, they can have leading zeroes, hyphens, brackets, spaces, plus signs, hash marks and words in them.

Comment: The code fragment shows `pressNumber` being built up for each digit, but `currrentNumber` being converted to string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jrturton says, you should store the phone number as a string instead of a number:

```
-(IBAction)press:(id)sender{
    pressedNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", pressedNumberString, [sender tag]];
    // or better yet:
    // pressedNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", pressedNumberString, sender.titleLabel.text];

    phonenumber.text = pressedNumberString
}
```